# Need to understand this summation with max notation

Tags: summation

Firstly, apologies needed for my math description if it does not sound right.

I have come across a paper where I saw a summation notation with a max function in it which I am little confused to understand. The formula is as follows:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{Ncm}\max_{i\le j\le k}\left\{\frac{n_{ij}}{n_i}\right\}$$

The context of the above formula - It is a purity function and it is used to evaluate whether the quality of detection of communities is good. You can know more from [Here](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2107829)

Here, $N_{cm}$ represents the number of detected communities, $n_{ij}$ refers to the number of nodes belonging to topic j and community i, $n_{i}$ refers to the number of nodes in community i. k is the number of topics in the network.

Now, can anyone please guide me thorough about how can I break this notation with numbers and understand it correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Apparently $k$ is some fixed value. For each value of $i$ in the set $\{1,2,\ldots,Ncm\}$ you’re to choose the largest of the $k-i+1$ fractions

$$\frac{n_{ii}}{n_i},\frac{n_{i,i+1}}{n_i},\frac{n_{i,i+2}}{n_i},\ldots,\frac{n_{ik}}{n_i}\;;$$

the value of the expression is the sum of these choices. Without more context that’s all I can tell you.

Comment: Thanks Brian for the answer. I really appreciate your response. I have added context of the formula in the question. What I have been trying to do is first understand this formula and then implement this into R. But being new to understanding both at these, I am finding little difficult to comprehend. Can you also please guide me how can implement it into R?

Comment: I was trying to understand the explanation that you gave but still I am having difficulty. Can you give a simple implementation level example? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As requested, here’s a concrete example; I have no idea whether the numbers are at all plausible, but they at least illustrate the computation.

First let me correct the expression; it’s

$$Purity=\frac1{N_{cm}}\sum_{i=1}^{N_{cm}}\max_{1\le j\le K}\frac{n_{ij}}{n_i}\;,$$

where $N_{cm}$ is the number of communities, $n_{ij}$ is the number of nodes belonging to topic $j$ and community $i$, and $n_i$ is the number of members in community $i$. $K$ is the number of topics.

Suppose that $K=3$, so that there are three topics, and the algorithm detects $N_{cm}=2$ communities, which I’ll call $C_1$ and $C_2$. Suppose that $C_1$ has $n_1=4$ members, and $C_2$ has $n_2=7$ members. Finally, suppose that the numbers $n_{ij}$ are given by the following array:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
i\backslash j&1&2&3\\ \hline
1&0&2&3\\
2&7&2&1
\end{array}$$

Then

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^2\max_{1\le j\le 3}\frac{n_{ij}}{n_i}&=\max_{1\le j\le 3}\frac{n_{1j}}4+\max_{1\le j\le 3}\frac{n_{2j}}7\\
&=\max\left\{\frac{n_{11}}4,\frac{n_{12}}4,\frac{n_{13}}4\right\}+\max\left\{\frac{n_{21}}7,\frac{n_{22}}7,\frac{n_{23}}7\right\}\\
&=\frac14\max\{n_{11},n_{12},n_{13}\}+\frac17\max\{n_{21},n_{22},n_{23}\}\\
&=\frac14\max\{0,2,3\}+\frac17\max\{7,2,1\}\\
&=\frac34+\frac77\\
&=\frac74\;,
\end{align*}$$

and $Purity=\frac12\cdot\frac74=\frac78$.